# JavaScript Local Storage with Sliding Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, local-storage, refresh

I'm working on a website and I'm very new to javascript. I have 6 buttons and when they are pressed they slide a drop-down downward with data on it. When one is pressed it retracts all the other ones in order to take up the same amount of space. It works well and it's all I have managed to do with my knowledge of javascript. I now need these dropdowns to remember what position they were in when the page refreshes with local storage. I have found a few examples online of local storage but I tried probably 30 of them at this point over the last few days and cant gets them to fit my needs. I really stuck on how I can incorporate local storage to remember the position of these dropdowns when the page refreshes.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy2").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel2").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy3").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel3").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy4").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel4").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy5").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel5").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy6").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel6").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy7").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel7").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy8").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel8").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel9")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel9").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy9").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel9").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel4")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel4").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel5")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel5").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel6")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel6").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel7")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel7").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel8")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel8").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
**NEW TRY OF CODE BASED OFF OF COMMENT**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div>
            <div style="position: relative; left: 20%;" class='div-toggle' id='flippy'>
                click me1
            </div>
            <div style="position: relative; left: 20%;" class='div-toggle' id='flippy2'>
                click me2
            </div>
            <div style="position: relative; left: 20%;" class='div-toggle' id='flippy3'>
                click me3
            </div>
        </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      let first = localStorage.getItem('open-toggle');
      if (first) $(`#${first}`).trigger('click');
      $(".div-toggle").click(function() {
        $(".div-toggle").not(this).slideToggle("normal");
        localStorage.setItem('open-toggle', $(this).attr('id'))
      })
    })
</script>




    <script>
$("#flippanel").hide();
$("#flippanel2").hide();
$("#flippanel3").hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flippy").click(function() {
        $("#flippanel").slideToggle("normal");
        if ($("#flippanel2")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel2").slideToggle();
        }
        if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#flippy2").click(function() {
            $("#flippanel2").slideToggle("normal");
            if ($("#flippanel")[0].style.display != "none") {
                $("#flippanel").slideToggle();
            }
            if ($("#flippanel3")[0].style.display != "none") {
                $("#flippanel3").slideToggle();
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#flippy3").click(function() {
            $("#flippanel3").slideToggle("normal");
            if ($("#flippanel")[0].style.display != "none") {
                $("#flippanel").slideToggle();
            }
            if ($("#flippanel2")[0].style.display != "none") {
                $("#flippanel2").slideToggle();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet shows a couple things: how to properly open and close the toggles according to your specs. It also shows how to store the open toggle in localStorage, find it when the page loads and trigger. Those parts are commented out because they fail in the snippet sandbox - but uncomment them in your code and test.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // let first = localStorage.getItem('open-toggle');
 // if (first) $(`#${first}`).trigger('click');
  $(".div-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".div-toggle").not(this).slideToggle("normal");
   // localStorage.setItem('open-toggle', $(this).attr('id'))
  })
})
```

```css
.div-toggle {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='div-toggle' id='flippy1'>
    click me
  </div>

  <div class='div-toggle' id='flippy2'>
    click me
  </div>

  <div class='div-toggle' id='flippy3'>
    click me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me, unfortunately. I'll add an edit of my new code but it doesn't work for me. I am starting to take small javascript classes so I can understand this a little better but I'm coming up on a deadline and I'm not getting it as fast as I need to. I also am looking for two separate buttons, each one when pressed displays unique to the button text below it and the same for the other one. When one is pressed it retracts just the text of all the other ones and then displays its own, while having local storage capabilities. I'm not even sure if this is possible now.